# How to specify conditions for excel COUNTIFS function?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, datatable

What I am trying to do is count the number of values in an excel column named "Report Deadline" that are after today, but also have no value(blank) or have the value "N/A" in another column named "Date Report Issued"

I am unfamiliar with how to specify conditions for the COUNTIFS function but I also don't know if there is a better way to do it rather than use COUNTIFS

This is what I have

```
=COUNTIFS(Table22[Report Deadline],">=" & TODAY(),Table22[Date Report Issued],"=" "",Table22[Date Report Issued],"=" "N/A")
```

Comment: Remove the `"="`

Comment: Ok thank you that seemed to have fixed my syntax errors. What would be the way to specify that the Date Report Issued Column can be "" OR "N/A"? @findwindow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really have an "OR" condition in a `COUNTIFS`.
I would suggest doing two separate `COUNTIFS`, and then adding them together. Like so:

```
=COUNTIFS(Table22[Report Deadline],">=" & TODAY(),Table22[Date Report Issued], "")
+
COUNTIFS(Table22[Report Deadline],">=" & TODAY(),Table22[Date Report Issued], "N/A")
```

If you really wanted to do it in a single expression, you could put "N/A" and "" into an array and wrap the `COUNTIFS` in a `SUM`. But it would essentially be doing the same thing as the two separate functions and arguably not be as easy to read:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Table22[Report Deadline],">=" & TODAY(),Table22[Date Report Issued],{"","N/A"}))
```

Comment: Re "arguably not be as easy to read", perhaps for two conditions only, as here. But imagine a scenario in which we were talking about a dozen or more? Then the `SUM` with array construction certainly wins in terms of both readibility and maintenance.

Comment: @JosWoolley which is exactly why I said "arguably". That is also why I provided both examples, and left left the reader to make a choice based on their specific use case and preference.